# file_log does not appear in docker image

Tags: python, docker, docker-image, logfile

I have a python selenium project in which I create a file_log.log with the following code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="../file_log.log",
    format='%(asctime)s:  %(levelname)s:  %(message)s',
    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S',
    filemode='w'
)

logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

when I run my code everything is working and the file_log.log shows all the "steps" of my "automation driver" as I expected.

I create a docker image from the following docker file:

```
RUN mkdir /opt/folder_1
ADD project_on_my_machine /opt/folder_1
RUN pip install -r /opt/folder_1/requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "/opt/folder_1/main.py"]
```

when I lunch docker run -it docker_image everything is working but:

1. if I press CTRL+C while the docker run is going , this does not "kill" the execution of the program; the program stops only at its end.
2. no file_log.log has been created as if I launch this command ("docker run -it docker_image ls /opt/folder_1"), only these files will be "shown":

errors.py         main.py           settings.py       utils.py
log.py            requirements.txt  user.py

Comment: Would you mind splitting this into two separate questions?

Comment: Look in the root directory for the log file.

Comment: Why SHOUT at us in the TITLE? What did we do to you?

Comment: @DanielWalker I already checked with the same docker command even in the parent directory (docker run -it docker_image ls /opt) and it is not shown

Comment: No, I mean the *root* directory, /.

Comment: @DanielWalker I tried and this is the output:  


bin    etc    lib    mnt    proc   run    srv    tmp    var
dev    home   media  opt    root   sbin   sys    usr



I think there is some reason that makes alpine not to create the log_file. 

I think I need to do something like this ("https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/")